# Atualizando dados com entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

No projeto que estou desenvolvendo, MVC5, Entity 6, simplesmente não estou conseguindo atualizar os dados.

O Código:

```
zyon.TB_Cliente.Attach(cliente);
zyon.Entry(cliente).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
zyon.SaveChanges();
```

Que funciona quando crio o banco de dados através do projeto, não está funcionando quando conecto a um banco já existente.

Os dados são salvos normal com:

```
zyon.TB_Cliente.Add(cliente);
zyon.SaveChanges();
```

Mas a atualização não ocorre. =T

Comment: Coloca o código de toda sua action de *edit* pra ficar mais claro ?

Comment: Esse é todo o código.

Comment: Esse banco de dados existente foi criado pela aplicação?

Comment: Não. Banco antigo.

Comment: Resolvido o problema?

Comment: Eu já tive esse erro, concertei fazendo o seguinte: 
Primeiro busco no banco quem eu quero editar :
var Cliente = 'contexto.entidade.firstOrDefault(x=> x.Id == IdDoCliente);

Ai começo a edição: 
Cliente.nome = cliente.nome..

e ai sim dou o contexto.SaveChanges()

Answer (score 1):

Eu faço assim, ve se te ajuda.

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[ControleDeAcesso(TipoAcao.Normal)]
public ActionResult Detalhar(string btnSubmit, Memo model)
{
    // Verifica se o modelo é válido, senão retorna para a View
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(model);

    using (var db = new ERPContext()) // Cria o contexto de conexão
    {
        var memo = db.Memo.Find(model.MemoID); // Busco o registro
        var retorno = FlexGestor.Helpers.EntidadeBaseExt.ValidarRegistro(memo, TipoAcao.Gravar); // Valido o registro
        if (retorno != "")
        {
            TempData["MsgRetornoError"] = retorno;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        if (btnSubmit != "Excluir")
            UpdateModel(memo);  // Se não for exclusão, pego os dados do model e jogo no registro buscado
        Helpers.EntidadeBaseExt.AtribuirValores(memo, btnSubmit); // Função interna minha
        db.Entry(memo).State = EntityState.Modified; // Seto como modificado 
        db.SaveChanges(); // Salvo

        // Retorno para a view conforme ação original
        if (btnSubmit == "Excluir")
            return RedirectToAction("Index", controller);

        return RedirectToAction("Detalhar", controller, new { id = model.MemoID });
    }
}
```

Comment: Se você usou o `Find` para buscar o registro no Banco e em nenhum momento vi você setar `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` para false, acredito que o proprio contexto já esteja a monitorar esta entidade, então modificar o seu State de forma manual é desnecesaria.

Answer (score 1):

Coloque seu código dentro de um ModelState e adicione break point no método para ver se está ocorrendo algum erro com os dados editados.

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       zyon.TB_Cliente.Attach(cliente);
       zyon.Entry(cliente).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
       zyon.SaveChanges();
    }
    return View(cliente);
```

Comment: Não acho que isto responda a pergunta, pois um Modelo invalido no maximo faria o SaveChanges levantar uma excessão do tipo `DbValidationError` e acredito que isto ele teria detectado.

Comment: @TobyMosque como ele não adicionou um possível erro, eu adicionei apenas para ajudar a debugar, para verificar se ele está enviando um modelo válido para ser editado. Aguardei a resposta do autor para poder elaborar uma resposta para o problema. Não postei no comentário, pois achei que ficaria um pouco "embolado" para a compreensão.

Comment: Também acho estranho não está salvando, acredito que o problema não esteja neste bloco de código, mas na modelagem.

Comment: @TobyMosque eu tive um problema muito parecido uma vez. Neste caso o edit (que necessita de um id) não estava recebendo o ID, não deixando o modelo válido, consequentemente não salvando. Mas como o autor não se manifestou, deve ter encontrado a solução.

Answer (score 1):

Três alternativas. Usar a versão específica em vez da object:

```
zyon.Entry<TB_Cliente>( client ).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

Ir direto no `ChangeTracker` fazer a modificação:

```
zyon.ChangeTracker.Entries<TB_Cliente>().First( x => x.Entity == client ).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

Ou, se for um trecho de código em particular, e já estiver cansado dos erros um tanto misteriosos do EF, fazer os dois:

```
zyon.TB_Cliente.Attach( client );
zyon.Entry( client ).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
zyon.ChangeTracker.Entries<TB_Cliente>().First( x => x.Entity == client ).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
zyon.SaveChanges();
```

---

Pela [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696238(v=vs.113).aspx), `DbContext.Entry(object)` deveria ser uma forma válida de acessar as propriedades de um objeto rastreado ou anexado, e [mudar o State para Modified](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/update-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx) seria todo o necessário para forçar o UPDATE dos dados. Mas de vez em quando não rola, simplesmente.

A versão genérica, caso queira fazer UPDATE em vários objetos de uma maneira imediata (e fora da transação oficial!):

```
public void DetachedUpdate(T obj)
{
    using (var context = new Context())
    {
        context.Set<T>().Attach(obj);
        context.ChangeTracker.Entries<T>().First(e => e.Entity == obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você primeiro deve verificar se o Id da sua entidade está preenchido e então poderia tentar desta forma fazendo um tratamento no estado do objeto, onde DbBase é seu contexto e TEntity sua entidade, no caso cliente.

```
public void Atualiza(TEntity entidadeEntity)
{
    if (DbBase.Entry(entidadeEntity).State == EntityState.Detached)
        DbBase.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entidadeEntity);

    DbBase.Entry(entidadeEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    DbBase.SaveChanges();
}
```